# Cancellation property of the Stone Cech compactification

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, semigroups, compactification, topological-semigroups

Let $G$ be a discrete countable group and let $\beta G$ be the Stone-Cech compactification of $G$, which has the structure of a semigroup.

Is $\beta G$ left cancellable? What about right cancellable? (With respect to the semigroup operation).

By that I mean if $xy=xz$ does that mean that $y=z$? What about the if $yx=zx$?

This question is related to the question proposed in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428924/stone-%c4%8cech-compactification-as-a-semigroup.

Comment: I observe that you asked several questions, here and on Mathoverflow, but you never accepted any answer. Do you know you have this possibility? See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: @J.-E.Pin I did not know that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is negative if the group is infinite. In fact, Theorems 5 and 6 of [1] give a complete characterization of the semigroups $S$ such that $\beta S$ is left [right] cancellative. Condition (f) of these theorems is the most interesting part:

**Theorem 6**. Let $S$ be a discrete semigroup. Then $\beta S$ is left cancellative if and only if there exist a finite group $G$ and a [right zero semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_semigroup#Right_zero_semigroup) $R$ such that $S$ is isomorphic to $G \times R$.

**Theorem 7**. Let $S$ be a discrete semigroup. Then $\beta S$ is right cancellative if and only if there exist a finite group $G$ and a [left zero semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_semigroup#Left_zero_semigroup) $L$ such that $S$ is isomorphic to $L \times G$.

Thus if $S$ is a discrete countable infinite group, it is not of the above form and hence is neither left nor right cancellative.

[1] N. Hindman and D. Strauss, [Characterization of simplicity and cancellativity in $\beta S$](http://nhindman.us/research/cancellative.pdf). *Semigroup Forum* **75** (2007), no. 1, 70--76.